# What's wrong with my for loop? Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

This for loop should iterate over even 'lines' in my input, as it holds the users name which I would like to place in a dictionary as a key, with a dictionary inside that key. My output does include the information I needed, but also odd lines which I do not want.
I'm new to python so I'm still trying to understand syntax.
Here's my code:

```
def get_name(string_input):
    split_fullstop = string_input.split('.')
    list = [] #creates a list                               
    for line in split_fullstop: 
        count = 0   
        if count % 2 == 0: #if count is even            
            list.append(line.split('is connected to')) #add info to 'list'      
            count += 1 #increase count
        names = {name[0]:{} for name in list}
    return names
```

And here's the output after printing the function:

```
{'': {}, 'Levi ': {}, 'Bryant ': {}, 'Jennie likes to play Super Mushroom Man, Dinosaur Diner, Call of Arms': {}, 'Olive likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Starfleet Commander': {}, 'Debra likes to play Seven Schemers, Pirates in Java Island, Dwarves and Swords': {}, 'Levi likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Seven Schemers, City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma': {}, 'Walter ': {}, 'Robin ': {}, 'John ': {}, 'Walter likes to play Seahorse Adventures, Ninja Hamsters, Super Mushroom Man': {}, 'Debra ': {}, 'Freda likes to play Starfleet Commander, Ninja Hamsters, Seahorse Adventures': {}, 'Mercedes likes to play The Legend of Corgi, Pirates in Java Island, Seahorse Adventures': {}, 'Ollie ': {}, 'Robin likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords': {}, 'Bryant likes to play City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma, Super Mushroom Man': {}, 'Freda ': {}, 'Olive ': {}, 'Mercedes ': {}, 'John likes to play The Movie: The Game, The Legend of Corgi, Dinosaur Diner': {}, 'Jennie ': {}, 'Ollie likes to play Call of Arms, Dwarves and Swords, The Movie: The Game': {}}
```

Comment: @AntonProtopopov You should have mentioned it as an answer, upvote!!

Comment: You haven't written what the input is nor what the expected output is.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that all code at the same indentation level below the for-loop will be run EACH iteration. Therefore you are redefining the variables `count` and `names` at each item the for-loop goes through. As mentioned in one of the comments, `names` should be at the same indentation level as the `return` statement.

Redefining `count` at each iteration means you will always find `0 % 2 == 0`. It should be defined BEFORE the for-loop. Also, you only increment `count` when you run the `#if count is even` portion. So, assuming `count` is defined before the loop, you will see `0` as even, increment `count` and be left with an odd value of `1` forever.

Look at looping though indices and values simultaneously using `enumerate`. That way you need only check the even/odd value of the index.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your count is a error indentation, count is design to filter even line.

```
for line in split_fullstop: 
    count = 0   
    if count % 2 == 0: #if count is even            
        list.append(line.split('is connected to')) #add info to 'list'      
    count += 1 #increase count
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have used a "for each loop", which loops over every element in the iterable and built in functionality to only evaluate the even indexes. Instead of this, I think it is more clear and clean to use the function range.

```
range(0, len(split_fullstop), 2)
```

Evaluating only the even

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  Don't use built'in variables such as `list` because you'll overwrite them and it could lead to the unexpected behaviour in future. Use `l` for example for that.

Your line with `names = {name[0]:{} for name in list}` will be executed every step because it placed not in the same position as `if` statement. For steps where `count % 2 == 1` you'll add to your `dict` empty lists. But in your solution you redefine `count` in each step so you'll never get that as @Isaac Drachman mentioned. So just delete some spaces or tab and define `count` before `for` loop:

```
def get_name(string_input):
    split_fullstop = string_input.split('.')
    l = [] #creates a list            
    count = 0                      
    for line in split_fullstop: 
        if count % 2 == 0: #if count is even            
            l.append(line.split('is connected to')) #add info to 'list'      
            count += 1 #increase count
    names = {name[0]:{} for name in l}
    return names
```

Or you could rewrite it with `list comprehension` and `enumerate`:

```
def get_name(string_input):
    l = [line.split('is connected to') for i, line in enumerate(string_input.split('.')) if i % 2 == 0]
    names = {name[0]:{} for name in l}
    return names
```

Comment: The `names = ...` line looks like it's intended to run once at the end over the `list` that the for loop built. As such, it looks like it needs to be unindented a level, rather than indented another level.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just focus on your `count` variable, because that's the first thing that tells me there's an error:

```
for line in split_fullstop: 
    count = 0   
    if count % 2 == 0: #if count is even            
        # some code
    count += 1 #increase count
    #some code
return names
```

First of all, you're resetting the `count` variable on each loop with that `count = 0` inside the loop, so on EVERY loop `count%2` will be equal to `0`. This line should be OUTSIDE (before) the loop.

Second, you're increasing the variable inside that if condition `count%2 == 0`, if in one iteration, `count == 0`, then it will enter the if-part, and will increase the value to `count == 1`.
In the next (and all other) iteration, since `count == 1`, the inside of the if-part won't be executed and thus the `count` variable won't change.

So, it should be like:

```
count = 0   
for line in split_fullstop: 
    if count % 2 == 0: #if count is even            
        #some code
        count += 1 #increase count
return names
```